# Is the category of sup-lattices rigid?

Tags: category-theory, tensor-products, order-theory, lattice-orders, monoidal-categories

In *An Extension of the Galois Theory of Grothendieck* Joyal and Tierney show that the category $\mathsf{SupLat}$ of [sup-lattices](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/suplattice) is star-autonomous. By listing compact closed categories and $\mathsf{SupLat}$ seperately the [nLab entry on star-autonomous categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/star-autonomous+category) makes it seem as though $\mathsf{SupLat}$ is not rigid. However, some sources claim this to be the case (e.g. [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2215364/rigid-monoidal-categories-that-is-cocomplete) and [2](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/67090553A2F65C7BB793A916F7E08B33/S1446788715000506a.pdf/characterization-of-projective-quantales.pdf)). Let the duality functor on objects send each sup-lattice to its opposite poset. Take the usual tensor product of sup-lattices (for an explicit construction see [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3891985/concrete-description-of-the-tensor-product-of-suplattices)).

> What are the evaluation and coevaluation morphisms making $\mathsf{SupLat}$ into a rigid monoidal category?

Is the two-element lattice $\{ 0 < 1\}=\mathcal{P}(\{\ast\})$ the monoidal unit with respect to the given tensor product? If so, the right evaluation has to be a map $M \otimes M^* \cong \text{Hom}(M,M)^* \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\{\ast\})$? What are natural candidates?

Comment: I haven't thought carefully about the details, but the natural idea that comes to mind is: maps $M\to \{0<1\}$ are in bijection with $M^*$ by sending $f$ to the greatest element of $f^{-1}(0)$.  So, I would expect the right evaluation $\operatorname{Hom}(M,M)^*\to \{0<1\}$ to be the map corresponding to the identity $M\to M$ in this way.

Comment: Or, the natural bilinear map $M\times M^*\to\{0<1\}$ to consider would be the one that sends $(x,y)$ to $0$ iff $x\leq y$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The category of suplattices is not rigid.  If it were rigid, then in particular, for any suplattice $M$, the suplattice $\operatorname{Hom}(M,M)$ would be self-dual (since we would have $\operatorname{Hom}(M,M)\cong M^*\otimes M\cong(M\otimes M^*)^*\cong (M^*\otimes M)^* \cong \operatorname{Hom}(M,M)^*$).  But this is not true.

For instance, let $M=\{0,a,b,c,1\}$, with $a,b,$ and $c$ all incomparable.  A morphism $f:M\to M$ can be described as a triple $(x,y,z)$ with $x\vee y=x\vee z=y\vee z$, where $x=f(a),y=f(b)$, and $z=f(c)$.  There are only $9$ coatoms of $\operatorname{Hom}(M,M)$, namely the elements of the form $(x,1,1)$ or a permutation thereof, where $x$ is $a,b,$ or $c$.  Indeed, it is easy to see that any triple $(x,y,z)\neq (1,1,1)$ is less than or equal to one of these $9$ coatoms.  However, there are more than $9$ atoms of $\operatorname{Hom}(M,M)$: there are $9$ atoms of the form $(x,x,0)$ or a permutation thereof where $x$ is $a,b,$ or $c$, but $(a,b,c)$ is also an atom.  So $\operatorname{Hom}(M,M)$ is not isomorphic to its dual.

Comment: In your argument you need rigidity only for the isomorphism $ (M^*\otimes M)^* \cong \operatorname{Hom}(M,M)^*$, right? That is: You first use that in a rigid monoidal category the/a duality functor is monoidal. Then you utilize that $M \otimes M^* \cong \operatorname{Hom}(M,M)^*$ in $\mathsf{SupLat}$. Correct?

Comment: Yes, you could skip directly from $\operatorname{Hom}(M,M)$ to $(M\otimes M^*)^*$ in that way so rigidity is used only in the last step.

Comment: Thank you, elegant answer by the way.